# Cannot Delete a row from my table

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

I am using spring MVC and hibernate framework .i have 2 tables .those are Team and Releases.it has a one to many mapping.i can delete recodes from Releases,but when i delete from Team it gives bellow Error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [delete from Teams where teamID=?]; 
constraint [null]; 
nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: 
Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to delete all the records from Releases that has reference to Team you need to delete, and then the Team.

or use

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/DeleteTeam", method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public String editDeleteRecodes(@ModelAttribute NewTeams newTeams, BindingResult result, @RequestParam String action, Map<String, Object> map){
  
  Teams teams = new Teams();
  teams.setTeamID(newTeams.getTeamID());
  teamService.delete(teams);
  
  
  return "redirect:/";
  
  
 }

Comment: @user2991030 What? Post your code _in your question_ not (unformatted in an unreadable block) in a comment to an answer.

Comment: Add @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true) in Team class.

Comment: yes i put but stil it give error..this my code:@OneToMany(mappedBy = "teams",fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)                                                                                        Erro is:HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update; SQL [delete from Teams where teamID=?]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update

Answer (score 0):

Since your table `Teams` has a one to one mapping to table `Releases`, the exception clearly shows that you are violating an integrity constraint. Your query

```
delete from teams where id=?
```

tries to delete the record from table `Teams`, but since you have a mapping to `Releases`, you will first need to delete the referred row with `teamID` in table `Releases` and then delete the  corresponding row from `Teams` table.

Comment: ah cool...u answers is very clear...

@Override
 public void delete(Teams teams) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  session.getCurrentSession().delete(teams);
 }
can u give some sample code for that..

Comment: You should try it yourself. Try googling some solutions. The best way to learn is through practice. :) ..

Answer (score 0):

you are using hibernate method is wrong~！
that code:
"hibernate.update(sql);".

Comment: I am using this..@Override
 public void delete(Teams teams) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  session.getCurrentSession().delete(teams);
 }

Comment: i am usin Delete methode